# setItemChecked() view failing to change

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-activity, android-fragments

For some reason I cannot programatically set the checked row on a listview. It works correctly in the setOnItemLongClickListener.

After a screen rotation I'm trying to call setItemChecked() on my listview. According to the logs the correct row is checked but I do not see the changes.

If I load/refresh data I call the setupList() method below.
This method also gets called in the onCreate method if purchaseOrderArrayList is not null.

```
private void setupList() {

    mPurchaseOrderListView.setAdapter(new PurchaseOrderListAdapter(getActivity(), purchaseOrdersArrayList));

    if (mSelectedPurchaseOrderIndex != -1) {
        //this is where it does not work :(
        mPurchaseOrderListView.setItemChecked(mSelectedPurchaseOrderIndex, true);
        Log.v(Constants.LOG, "number of selections = " + mPurchaseOrderListView.getCheckedItemCount());
        Log.v(Constants.LOG, "id     of selections = " + mPurchaseOrderListView.getCheckedItemPosition());
        Log.v(Constants.LOG, "choice mode = " + mPurchaseOrderListView.getChoiceMode());
    }

    mPurchaseOrderListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

            // if actionMode is null "not started"
            if (mActionMode != null)
                return false;

            // Start the CAB
            mActionMode = getActivity().startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
            mActionMode.setTag(purchaseOrdersArrayList.get(position));
            mSelectedPurchaseOrderIndex = position;
            view.setActivated(true);
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the layout for my listview (fragment_purchase_orders.xml)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/centered_background"
tools:context="com.posmanagement.mamobile.PurchaseOrderFragment">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/purchaseOrderListView"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    />
```

This is the layout for the row (simple_row_layout.xml)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/simple_list_background"
android:clickable="false"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Item Description"
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:textColor="#191919"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="012548"
    android:id="@+id/subLabel"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:textColor="#646565"/>
```

And here is the layout for the background of the row (simple_list_background.xml)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">

<item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/yellow_color" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/green_color" android:state_activated="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/white_color"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using

```
view.setActivated(true)
```

I used

```
mPurchaseOrderList.setItemChecked(position, true)
```

Everything worked and I no longer needed to store the position. Therefore I removed `mSelectedPurchaseOrderIndex` variable. (Note I believe this is because the listview is contained within a fragment, if the listview is in an activity I do need to save the selected position)